# cannot connect to nsqd from another service defined in docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nsq

I have a service connecting to nsqd to produce and consume messages. I have integration tests connecting to it (broadcast address 127.0.0.1) and this works fine executing it locally in the cli or the ide.

Then I have created this service to up with docker-compose, but cannot connect to nsqd.

Following is my docker-compose file

```
version: '3'

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:4.0.9-alpine
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

  nsqlookupd:
    image: nsqio/nsq:v0.3.8
    command: /nsqlookupd
    ports:
      - "4160:4160"
      - "4161:4161"

  nsqd:
    image: nsqio/nsq:v0.3.8
    command: /nsqd --lookupd-tcp-address=nsqlookupd:4160 --broadcast-address=127.0.0.1
    links:
      - nsqlookupd:nsqlookupd
    ports:
      - "4150:4150"
      - "4151:4151"

  nsqadmin:
    image: nsqio/nsq:v0.3.8
    ports:
      - "4171:4171"
    links:
      - nsqlookupd:nsqlookupd
    command: /nsqadmin --lookupd-http-address=nsqlookupd:4161

  creator:
    build: "creator/"
    depends_on:
      - nsqlookupd
      - nsqd
      - redis
    environment:
      SERVER_ADDR: ":8080"
      NSQ_ADDR: "nsqd:4150"
      NSQ_TOPIC: "driver_locations"
      NSQ_CHANNEL: "ch"
      REDIS: "redis:6379"
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

Right now I don't care about the tests locally, just to have all the containers working properly.

I have tried changing the broadcast, removing the broadcast...
As they say in the docs https://nsq.io/deployment/docker.html#using-docker-compose this is the last thing I tried (basically the changes are the commands), with no luck:

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:4.0.9-alpine
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
  nsqlookupd:
    image: nsqio/nsq
    command: /nsqlookupd
    ports:
      - "4160"
      - "4161"
  nsqd:
    image: nsqio/nsq
    command: /nsqd --lookupd-tcp-address=nsqlookupd:4160
    depends_on:
      - nsqlookupd
    ports:
      - "4150"
      - "4151"
  nsqadmin:
    image: nsqio/nsq
    command: /nsqadmin --lookupd-http-address=nsqlookupd:4161
    depends_on:
      - nsqlookupd  
    ports:
      - "4171"
  creator:
    build: "creator/"
    depends_on:
      - nsqlookupd
      - nsqd
      - redis
    environment:
      SERVER_ADDR: ":8080"
      NSQ_ADDR: "nsqd:4150"
      NSQ_TOPIC: "driver_locations"
      NSQ_CHANNEL: "ch"
      REDIS: "redis:6379"
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

Answer (score 0):

Cache problem, sorry for that :facepalm:

What I told it wasn't working (removing the broadcast) IT IS

I have tried changing the broadcast, removing the broadcast...
As they say in the docs https://nsq.io/deployment/docker.html#using-docker-compose this is the last thing I tried (basically the changes are the commands), with no luck:

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:4.0.9-alpine
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
  nsqlookupd:
    image: nsqio/nsq
    command: /nsqlookupd
    ports:
      - "4160"
      - "4161"
  nsqd:
    image: nsqio/nsq
    command: /nsqd --lookupd-tcp-address=nsqlookupd:4160
    depends_on:
      - nsqlookupd
    ports:
      - "4150"
      - "4151"
  nsqadmin:
    image: nsqio/nsq
    command: /nsqadmin --lookupd-http-address=nsqlookupd:4161
    depends_on:
      - nsqlookupd  
    ports:
      - "4171"
  creator:
    build: "creator/"
    depends_on:
      - nsqlookupd
      - nsqd
      - redis
    environment:
      SERVER_ADDR: ":8080"
      NSQ_ADDR: "nsqd:4150"
      NSQ_TOPIC: "driver_locations"
      NSQ_CHANNEL: "ch"
      REDIS: "redis:6379"
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```